# "ich habe das Essen eingefroren" oder "ich habe das Essen eingefriert"

Tags: verb, infinitive

Hallo Freunde der deutschen Sprache!

Im Titel stehen zwei Sätze im Perfekt. Mir geht es darum, dass ich hier gern Meinungen zu den zwei Formen hätte.

Die Partizipien "eingefroren" und "eingefriert" klingen ähnlich. Allerdings finde ich, das es hier - aus meiner Sicht - eine klare Unterscheidung geben müsste.

Frage: Was ist die Grundform?
"einfrieren" oder "eingefrieren"?

Laut Duden ist beides bekannt. Ich persönlich (und ich kann es leider nicht nachweisen) finde, dass das zwei Handlungen sind.
Da ich mich hier nicht anders auszudrücken weiß, versuche ich es so:

Das "Einfrieren" ist für mich die Handlung wenn etwas passiv geschieht.
Mir "frieren..." die Finger "...ein"

Wohingegen das "Eingefrieren" für mich eine aktive Handlung darstellt.
Siehe Titel: Ich "eingefriere" das Essen".

Beide Sätze vom Präsenz in das Perfekt:
Mir sind die Finger "eingefroren".
Ich habe das Essen "eingefriert"

So. Nun behaupte ich, dass man die beiden Partizipien in den obigen zwei Sätzen nicht tauschen sollte, um die Handlung deutlich zu machen.
Ich habe ja nicht meine Finger in die TK gelegt und das Essen ist auch nicht plötzlich hart geworden.

Ich halte daher den Satz "Ich habe das Essen eingefriert" für korrekt und den anderen für falsch.
Wie ist denn Eure Meinung dazu?

Viele Grüße
Sebastian

Comment: Ich kenne "eingefriert" überhaupt nicht und würde es auch nicht verwenden. Für mich heißt das Partizip "eingefroren".

Comment: Ich nenne hier einen ähnlichen Fall:
nießen (die Nase juckt)
genießen (etwas ist lecker)

Hier wird wahrscheinlich in beiden Fällen das Partizip "genossen" verwendet.
Dann fehlen aber auch die beiden Ursprungs-Verweise.
Man kann dann nur noch durch den Kontext auf das Verb in der ersten Person Präsenz schließen.
Wenn man es jedoch genießt, genossen zu haben, wird es schwer.
In der Perfekt-Form würde das zu "Ich habe es genossen, genossen zu haben" ;)

Comment: Auch da ist meine Erfahrung anders - das mMn gängigere Partizip ist *geniest* (für niesen) und *genossen* für genießen.

Comment: Sorry, da hat mein Wiki mich in die Irre geführt. Das "Nießen" i. S. v "Nutzen" ist hier von mir falsch gewählt. Natürlich heißt es "niesen" (Nase juckt). Und in der Folge "geniest" und nicht "genossen"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich habe das Wort *eingefrieren* noch nie gehört, aber du hast Recht, es existiert im Duden und im Wiktionary. Vielleicht gibt es da regionale Unterschiede.

Deine Argumentation ist zunächst mal in sich schlüssig. Sie geht aber von einem normativen Standpunkt aus. Kern deiner These ist die Aufforderung, man solle beide Verben im Partizip unterscheiden.

Dem steht deskriptiv entgegen, dass das Partizip des Verbs *gefrieren* ebenfalls *gefroren* ist, und damit sich vom Partizip von *frieren* gerade nicht unterscheidet. Über die Üblichkeit des Partizips von *eingefrieren* kann ich nichts sagen, weil ich das Verb gar nicht kenne. Das Wiktionary gibt es mit *eingefroren* an, also im Widerspruch zu deiner Sollens-Argumentation. In jedem Fall scheint mir aber die Üblichkeit des Partizips *gefroren* zum Verb *gefrieren* überwältigend.

Damit scheint mir deine These ein wenig am tatsächlichen Sprachgebrauch vorbeiargumentiert. Es macht aus beschreibender Perspektive keinen Sinn, in der Sprache etwas als "falsch" zu bezeichnen, wenn die kompenten Sprecherinnen und Sprecher so reden. Am Ende basiert Sprache auf Konvention, nicht auf Logik.

Comment: Ngrams meint, "eingefroren" sei 1000-mal häufiger als "eingefriert". Das scheint mir ein starkes Argument für "eingefroren".

Comment: Danke für die Ausführung. Ich hatte wohl klar zum Ausdruck gebracht, dass es meine persönliche Ansicht ist und ich Eure Meinungen dazu gern hätte.
Dass das Verb eingefrieren nun mal nicht sehr häufig vorkommt, sollte jedoch ebenfalls nach meiner Meinung nicht als Indiz dafür zu sehen sein, dass es die weniger richtige Form ausdrückt.
Frei nach dem Motto: "Fresst Schei**, 100 Milliarden Fliegen können nicht irren" ;)

Der letzte Satz hätte meinem Deutschlehrer wohl gar nicht gefallen - Grüße an Herrn R.

Comment: Da ich neu bin, kann ich Dir kein Upvote geben. Markiert habe ich sie jedoch.
Schönen Tag...

Comment: @SebastianDhom auch wenn ich diese Antwort hier für richtig und gut formuliert halte (+1), ist es meist eine gute Idee, auf Antworten 1-2 Tage zu warten bevor man die beste Antworkt akzeptiert. Gerade bei Fragen nach Sprachgebrauch, der ja regional sehr unterschiedlich sein kann, kann da auch etwas später noch sehr hilfreiche Antwort kommen  Ein Upvote der Antwort sollte meines Wissen nach unabhängig von der Reputation möglich sein.

Comment: @Planetmaker: Leider nein, ich kann ein Upvote erst mit einer Rep 15 erzeugen.

Comment: Wieder was gelernt :) Danke.

Comment: @planetmaker FYI: Man kann auch nachträglich noch ändern, welche Antwort man als "akzeptiert" auswählt, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120568/is-it-possible-to-change-the-chosen-answer

Comment: @SebastianDhom Das berührt eine Grundsatzfrage im Umgang mit Sprache, die hier den Rahmen sprengt. Vielleicht ist dieser Thread auf unserer Meta-Seite interessant für dich: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/normative-fragen/

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: Vielen Dank für den Hinweis auf Deinen Post "Normative Fragen".
Ich werde zukünftig "...die Begrenztheit meines eigenen sprachlichen Horizonts bedenken"
Ich wünsche allen ein schönes Wochenende.